# The method or operation is not implemented Scanning Service with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net-core, inversion-of-control, autofac, ioc-container

Good morning, I have a problem.
I am trying to inject all classes that implement interfaces (Service and Repository) into the IoC container using Autofac by on response i got the error "NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented".

```
                                  The full stack trace:
```

[image]

The controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll() => _userContext.GetAlAsync().Result;
```

And the GetAll method implementation on UserService implementation look that,
The class IUserService implement marker interface IService to injectclass in IoC container:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAlAsync()
    {
        return await _user.GetAllAsync();
    }
```

The controller return correct value before using autofac to register type to IoC container

The implementation of ModuleContainer using Autofac:

```
public class ContainerModules : Autofac.Module
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ContainerModules(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterInstance(AutoMapperConfig.Initialize())
            .SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterModule<ServiceModules>();
        builder.RegisterModule<CommandModule>();
        builder.RegisterModule<RepositoryModule>();

    }
}
```

And the Service modules:

```
 public class ServiceModules :  Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var assembly = typeof(ServiceModules)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .Assembly;

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
            .Where(x => x.IsAssignableTo<IService>())
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<JwtHandler>()
            .As<IJwthandler>()
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<Encrypter>()
            .As<IEncrypter>()
            .SingleInstance();;                                             
        }
   }
```

Comment: Could you provide the whole stack trace of your exception?

Comment: ok i paste all stack trace

Comment: Try to get the inner exception from this `AggregateException`, it should be more helpful

Comment: I have trouble because i have the two class which implement IUserService

Comment: You may be scanning and registering with Autofac but Autofac isn't anywhere in the stack trace. It's not Autofac throwing that NotImplementedException, it's something in your code. You could get more views on this question if you make it more about ASP.NET Core and less about the Autofac part.

Comment: Also, any reason you're not letting the ASP.NET Core stuff be async all the way through? Why use `.Result` at all?
`[HttpGet] public Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAll() => _userContext.GetAlAsync();`

Comment: Could you provide more code? What is `_userContext`?